# Are the "Lord's offerings" the one's given during sacrifice?

Tags: deuteronomy, leviticus, sacrifice, offering

In Deuteronomy 18:1 (NASB)

> “The Levitical priests, the whole tribe of Levi, shall not have a portion or inheritance with Israel; **they shall eat the Lord’s offerings by fire and His property**.

Are the "Lord's offerings" the one's given during sacrifice? Asking this to understand the implications this will have in who can eat from the offerings (Leviticus 6-7).

Comment: I'm not sure you specified whether the Passover 'sacrifice' would be included, Exd 12:21, 2Ch 35:11? Otherwise I'd say you're reading the verse in only one way.

Comment: @user21676 do you think the passover is what's being spoken there?

Comment: You're the one with terms, you tell me.

Comment: @user21676 the term is there, «Lord’s offerings».

Comment: The phrase used in the question title was 'sacrifice', a term used to reference the passover(Exodus 12:27), hence my comment. If you were only talking about altar preparations maybe you may have stated that.

Comment: @user21676 I'm really talking about sacrifices (or offerings if you will).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the context:

Deuteronomy 18
New International Version

> 1 The Levitical priests—indeed, the whole tribe of Levi—are to have no allotment or inheritance with Israel. They shall live on the **food offerings presented to the Lord**, for that is their inheritance. 2They shall have no inheritance among their fellow Israelites; the Lord is their inheritance, as he promised them.
>
> 3 This is the share due the priests from the people who **sacrifice a bull or a sheep**: the shoulder, the internal organs and the meat from the head. 4You are to give them the firstfruits of your grain, new wine and olive oil, and the first wool from the shearing of your sheep, 5for the Lord your God has chosen them and their descendants out of all your tribes to stand and minister in the Lord’s name always.

There is no mention of the kinds of festivals or the kinds of offerings: 1. Burnt Offering  2. Grain Offering  3. Peace Offering  4. Sin Offering or  5. Guilt Offering.

https://www.gotquestions.org/Old-Testament-sacrifices.html (pointed out by Tiago in his comment)

> Each of these sacrifices involved certain elements, either animal or fruit of the field, and had a specific purpose. Most were split into two or three portions—**God’s** portion, the portion for the Levites or **priests**, and, if there was a third, a portion kept by the **person** offering the sacrifice. The sacrifices can be broadly categorized as either voluntary or mandatory offerings.

Deuteronomy 18 is a general description so that the sons of Levi have a summary understanding of roughly what belongs to them. It describes the case where the priests and Levites' share of the offering.
Deuteronomy 12 describes the case where the family ate a share of their offering:

> 4 You must not worship the Lord your God in their way. 5But you are to seek the place the Lord your God will choose from among all your tribes to put his Name there for his dwelling. To that place you must go; 6there bring your burnt **offerings** and **sacrifices**, your **tithes** and special **gifts**, what you have vowed to give and your freewill offerings, and the **firstborn** of your herds and flocks. 7 There, in the presence of the Lord your God, you and your families shall eat and shall rejoice in everything you have put your hand to, because the Lord your God has blessed you.

In both cases, the offerings were first entirely given to the Lord to be sanctified. They were holy food.

Leviticus 21:22

> He may eat the most holy food of his God, as well as the holy food;

Are the "Lord's offerings" the one's given during sacrifice and offerings?

Yes, they were set apart and sanctified first before consumption.

Deuteronomy 18:1
New International Version

> The Levitical priests--indeed, the whole tribe of Levi--are to have no allotment or inheritance with Israel. They shall live on the **food offerings presented** to the LORD, for that is their inheritance.

The detail of who can eat what and when is described separately in Leviticus 7.

Comment: 'Levites(non-Aaronic priests) receive a portion of it': It would certainly help if you had a verse(literally, not dynamic equivalence), other than that suggested by the question, to support this claim.

Comment: I hope it's also clear that I am not referring to the tithe(nasb: property); the translation you have used has blurred that difference with altar preparations(e.g. all food offerings = any Levite can eat thereof, verse 1).

Comment: "Then the priests and Levites receive a portion of it."... that might be what we can extract from the question yes, but I agree with @user21676 that the answer isn't justifying that properly. The approach I can think of might imply showing which offerings exist and who is allowed to eat from it. The best I could find was [this article](https://www.gotquestions.org/Old-Testament-sacrifices.html).

Comment: Hi Tony Chan! Would you care to improve the answer taking in consideration this feedback?

Comment: I didn't see the feedback. I'll take a look.

Comment: The statement that any family could eat of the offerings is not at all explicit in that chapter(ch. 12), and does not at all address the very strong probability that Israel as a whole was being referenced there, part of which constituted the Aaronic priests, the ones who actually ate of those offerings. In other words when speaking in general terms, those phrases have meaning to the people as a whole(e.g. 'you shall be to me a kingdom of priests and an holy nation' did not give non-Aaronic priests the right to offer sacrifices on the altar; I hope you see what I'm getting at).

Comment: I'll just say I think the phrase 'you and your households', regardless of its interpretation(e.g. - Deut. 14: 26, where although it would seem the Levites were the sole ones being emphasized with regard to being joyful upon receiving the tithe[compare Num 18:30-31] yet Deut. 12:12 makes it otherwise possible, though not emphatic) has little to do with interpreting 12:7, whereby the use of the phrase does not necessarily mean that the people that did the eating were also the antecedent of the 'you and your households'(whereby on the one hand it talked about Levites and on the other, the nation)

Comment: Btw if you are going to persist in using dynamically equivalent translations, I'm pretty  sure most of what I said won't make much sense; the translation you used for Deut. 12:7 has distorted the sense of the underlying text(or at least they've made that decision for you).

Comment: Compare also Deuteronomy 12:17-18, where only the Levites were referenced, yet uses the same terminology as verse 7(i.e. you will rejoice in all you put your hands unto). So while it is still possible for verse 7's 'rejoicing' to be referring to non-priests, it seems to be not so emphasized(in that verse). Rather it seems it is that attribute of Israel being emphasized(the priesthood), which is then attributed to the rest of Israel.

Comment: Basically the evidence of Numbers 5:9-10 is the proof that only the priests ate of the altar preparations(the evident exception would Leviticus 22:11, wherein a stranger that was part of his house was permitted to partake of those meals).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Israelite_cuisine

Comment: Also the priest's daughter, there's a section there with certain conditions whether she may partake of the meals(Lev 22:12-13).

Comment: I didn't answer who can eat what and when. I'd encourage you to put your info together and post an answer.